# Powering 36V motor with 48V LiPo battery through a motor controller

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am planning to use 36V BLDC motors from a hoverboard, ([this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CV1U7D0))
with [this](https://www.enertionboards.com/focbox-speed-controller/focbox-unity-dual-motor-foc-controller-esc/)  motor controller.

The controller mentioned can handle up to 50V, 60A continuous. I would appreciate it if someone can enlighten me on whether using a 48V LiPo battery to power the 36V motors using this motor controller is feasible.

The reason why I am not going with a 36V battery is that somehow it's not available around, only 48V. I guess business and market demands.

Comment: Questions about the *usage* of *consumer products* or their parts that *do not come with "real" specifications* are problematic.  What sort of "voltage rating" is the 36 volts?   If it were an *insulation* rating, that would be a problem, similarly a speed rating factored through to voltage is something to take with concern (but consider not only the motor but also what it spins).  In contrast, many types of motor voltage ratings are more nominal than absolute, or even simply data points on a performance chart.  But without engineering details, no engineering answer is possible.

Comment: A product link is not an engineering spec for the components comprising the product.  You should probably try to find a *discussion forum* where people who have repurposed these or are interested in doing so discuss what they have been able to figure out.  That is not the mission of *this* site.

Comment: I have added a link to the motor if it helps. I would assume the given voltage as the nominal voltage

Comment: So, yes, not enough information.  You could try it out.  The danger, aside from the tuning being off and the whole thing oscillating madly (and burning up the motor) is that you'll push the thing too hard (and burn up the motor).  You may be able to pull it off by just building it and riding it while monitoring the motor temperature carefully until you learn how to limit how much you ask of the motor.

Comment: I believe it should be possible based on what's mentioned in these two links: https://endless-sphere.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=71816 and https://endless-sphere.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=70157 what do you think of this?

Comment: 48V is the nominal voltage of the battery.  It may have considerably more than 50V at the terminals when fully charged.  That type of BLDC motor controller tends to regulate motor current by PWM of full voltage pulses, taking advantage of the fact that motors tend to be sensitive to RMS current rather than instantaneous voltage.  You're likely to end up in a scenario where you're using a device rated for 50V to switch pulses of more than 50V at a motor only rated for 36V.  There's actually a pretty decent chance it would work, at least temporarily, but you can see where it might go wrong.

Comment: Also a quick google search appears to indicate 36V Li-ion packs are ubiquitous.

Answer (score 0):

As from all the comments, I see that running the motor with a higher rating battery will result in killing it at some point. Thus, I ended up buying a 36v battery, however, it was a 6 hours one-way drive to get to the nearest shop that sells them and it was the last piece.

I don't consider this as a real answer though. I am looking forward to find someone who managed to do it and share his experience on how he managed it. But, the Science says the motor will die.

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted for this since for this question this might be the answer that stands and I think we're better off when askers follow through, so thank you for taking the time to outline what the solution was for you.  It's quite possible that if you had hooked up and ran it from that 48V battery that it would have worked just fine, even a chance it would be long term stable, but more likely it would affect the Mean Time Before Failure(MTBF) of the motor.

Comment: There is a workaround, to use a voltage converter to step down the voltage before feeding the motor controller, but this wasn't recommended likely because of the disadvantages of decreased efficiency, potentially higher cost, design difficulties and physical size constraints, plus an additional potential failure point.  I'm not experienced with it, but I would guess voltage converter design/selection is significantly harder with a decent size reactive load.